# right i have this code and the system command keeps coming up with errors

Tags: c

I am trying to make a brute-force

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int i;
        while (i <= 999999 ) {
                system("./lock", i); 
                i++;
        }
        printf("Error. Unable to crack file.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I am trying to put the value "i" in the system command so that when I run it against my file it will get the pin. but I keep getting errors will the system command and I want it to run in the Linux terminal.

like this

```
./lock 1
./lock 2
./lock 3
etc.
```

But if you know a way of detecting if it has been cracked, please add that as well. if you can.

Comment: The compiler should warn you that you are using an *uninitialised* variable `i`, and that `system()` has too many arguments.

Comment: [man system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)

Comment: well i use man 3 system. and it did not help all. i have searched on google for 5 hours to find the problem and i still can't see the problem.

Comment: I get, [`prog.c:9:17: error: too many arguments to function ‘system’`](https://ideone.com/GIBxGs). Is that error message not clear enough?

Comment: 5 hours, and you did not figure out that `system` cannot take two parameters?? It only takes ONE parameter.  ***You*** are responsible for combining all the input into that one parameter.  (see my answer, and the use of `sprintf`)

Comment: Then the problem is waaaay deeper.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 999999 )
    {
        char cmd[100];
        sprintf(cmd, "./lock %d", i);
        if (system(cmd) == 0)
        {
            printf("Success with i = %d\n", i);
            exit(0);
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return !printf("Error. Unable to crack file.\n");
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `sprintf` was confused with `sprintf_s`.

Comment: it worked but stops at the first try. i am trying to find a way to fix this.

Comment: Then you have not described with enough detail what the `lock` program does, or when it succeeds, or what it does.